# Setting up redirect rule in wordpress that passes parameters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to create URL redirect rule in my htaccess that takes a URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/product-category/[category-name]

and redirects to the URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/parts?category=[category-name]

How can I do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.+)$ parts?category=$1 [QSA]
```

In your root `.htaccess` file.

Whether this is the best solution for integrating with WordPress, I'm not sure. Or some further config in WordPress may be needed to make it use those URLs for ones it generates. Anyway, it will get you started so they are translated in the first place.

The [QSA] flag means that you can have query strings on your URLs and category=x will get appended to them instead of replacing them, which is probably what you want.